# How to copy sitemap.xml to build folder with React & Webpack?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, xml-sitemap, webpack

I have a `sitemap.xml` file in public folder. When I build the React application, the `sitemap.xml` file is not present in the `dist/build` folder.

What Webpack configuration is needed to achieve that? How does robots.txt need to be set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the webpack-config for serving a file to build folder witha a custom name

[image]

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|xml)$/i,
            type: 'asset/resource',
        },
        {
            test: /\.xml/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'sitemap.xml',
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.txt/,
            type: 'asset/resource',
            generator: {
                filename: 'robots.txt',
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
            type: 'asset/inline',
        },
    ],
},
```

Finally make sure you import that file inside your react application or else it will not be served to build folder

[image]